# struts 2 jquery sj:select with bootstrap-select styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, struts2, struts2-jquery

this gets bootstrap select styles correctly:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="status"><s:text name="en.naturaleza"/></label>
            <s:select id="status" cssClass="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" data-header="Select a condiment" list="#{'0':'All','1':'Public','2':'Private','3':'State-Subsidised'}"/>
          </div>
```

but this doesnt:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="comunidad"><s:text name="en.comunidad"/></label>
            <s:url id="remoteurl1" action="cargaComunidades" namespace="/json"/>
            <sj:select href="%{remoteurl1}" 
              id="comunidad"
              name="colegio.comunidad"                                                                                                         
              list="listaComunidades" 
              listKey="id" 
              listValue="descripcion" 
              formIds="buscar-colegio"
              headerKey="0"
              headerValue="Todas"                                                                                               
              cssClass="selectpicker show-tick form-control"
            />
          </div>
```

to use struts 2 jquery plugin you have to include

```
<sj:head/>
```

which fetchs its own jquery scripts and must be a conflict with jquery you declare by yourself

any ideas??

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try the [Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-bootstrap/)?